# Successfully passing a variable between two javascript files that is assigned based on id

Tags: javascript, variables

***Fairly new to Javascript***

I have cloned images with id = 0,1,2,3... and changed their src dynamically and am trying to pull those id's when theyre clicked, assign them to a variable and then pass that variable to a new javascript file for use. I have figured out how to assign them to variables within a function and when I alert the assigned variable inside the function it alerts the correct variable, but when I go to the next .js file and try to alert the variable there, it shows up as "undefined".

I declared var w outside of the function and when I go to the other .js file it recognizes w as a string... so I'm confused.

Might have something to do with page reload???

Stuck on this for quote a while, please help

```
<img class = img; id = "0" src="..."  width="100%" height="100%">
</div>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("img").click(function(){
      w = this.id;
      alert(w);
  });
});
```

Comment: What do you mean with: _"when I go to the next .js file"_ ? Can you please add all relevant code/markup to reproduce the problem -> [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

If your variable `w` is a global variable (i.e. defined outside any function), then your approach should work **as long as the page is not reloaded**.

If you want your variable to be saved even after page reload, consider using [`localStorage`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_win_localstorage.asp), which saves your variable in the browser.

In your first JS file:

```
localStorage.setItem('w', some_value);
```

In your second file:

```
var w = localStorage.getItem('w');
console.log(w);
```

Comment: First .js File:      `$(document).ready(function(){
  $("img").click(function(){
      localStorage.setItem(w, this.id);
      alert(w);
  });
});`              Second .js File: `localStorage.getItem(w);
alert(w);` I think you are right as a page reload occurs when traversing the two files, but I made your suggested change and it still shows up as undefined. Did I implement it incorrectly?

Comment: @Beastmode7843 Glad this helps! If this answered your question, please consider upvoting/marking as answer. Have a good day!